# Adding image to Azure table from Android Xamarin Application

Tags: android, arrays, azure, xamarin, bitmap

My current method of converting the image's bitmap to a byte array to a string crashes the application. The code is below

```
sampleIV.BuildDrawingCache();
                            Bitmap bm = sampleIV.DrawingCache;
                            byte[] finalData;

                            using (var stream= new MemoryStream())
                            {
                                bm.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 0, stream);
                                finalData = stream.ToArray();
                            }
                            addBook.image =finalData;
                        await booksTable.InsertAsync(addBook);
```

If the line is removed then it does work so this is the problem does anybody have a solution for uploading a photo to an azure table.

EDIT:
New code with now converting to base 64 string which does have a length less than 500,000 and a breakpoint in the catch is being reached.

```
 sampleIV.BuildDrawingCache();
                            Bitmap bm = sampleIV.DrawingCache;
                            byte[] finalData;


                            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
                            {
                                bm.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 0, stream);
                                finalData = stream.ToArray();
                            }string s = Convert.ToBase64String(finalData);

                               addBook.image = s;
try
                            {
                                await booksTable.InsertAsync(addBook);

                            }
                            catch (Exception)
                            {
                                int x = 45;
                            }
```

Comment: Add the Exception/Stacktrace to your question. And what are the length of those arrays?

Comment: Are you trying to save data in Azure Storage Table?

Comment: what is "the line" that causes the crash?  What is the specific exception?

Comment: Yes @GauravMantri, I am trying to add to azure storage table. Also jason and sushihangover no line is the exact crash point, it just stops running after the await insert async and then goes into break mode.

Comment: To add binary data (i.e. attribute of type Edm.Binary) in Azure Tables, you would need to convert that to a Base64 string if I am not mistaken.

Comment: @SushiHangover the length of the arrays are under 500,000. I don't have traces

Comment: @TomBraccia And the exception/innerexception/stacktrace is?

Comment: @SushiHangover I am unsure how to find this because the app just goes into break mode stating an unhandled exception has occurred because the problem happens with the azure side that to my understanding won't show up in the stack trace?

Comment: @TomBraccia Confused, your update states your `Catch` is being reached? If it is a Azure API exception, assumably you should be able to review the inner-exception.

Comment: Well @SushiHangover you taught me something  new, after going through a few error types, I was able to find x83 = "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceInvalidOperationException: request entity too large\n  at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceHttpClient+<ThrowInvalidResponse>d__24.MoveNext () [0x001ec] in <ab12dd35a79843cbbb4e1cdb3ddf742... S.length is 450,000, so I'm not sure if that is the problem, and how do i make it  smaller.

Comment: @TomBraccia My understanding is an Azure table property is limited to 32Kb. (I have not use them in years, but I do not believe that restriction has changed, along with ~1MB total per row, 255 max props, etc... ) In general it is not somewhere you should store images... Typically you would store them in an Azure Blob storage  or as Azure Content (CDN) and use that reference as a Azure Table property

Comment: @SushiHangover okay, I will look into that. Thank you.